# Does uploading new ASPX page will force IIS to recompile the website?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Does uploading an  aspx page with only HTML content change to a web project will cause IIS to recompile the site?

Comment: It should not be. I will wait to hear from expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IIS will precompile the Website, even if the project is a Web Application, I say it because the Website is

> compiled dynamically (automatically) by ASP.NET on the server the
>   first time a request is received after the site has been installed or
>   updated

and in the Web Application

> You explicitly compile the source code on the computer that is used
>   for development or source control

[From Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)

But even in the Web Application project, [web pages (.aspx), user controls (.ascx), and MVC Razor views (.cshtml and .vbhtml) are compiled dynamically on the server by the ASP.NET compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now, answering your question, **yes, it will compile because it is a .aspx file**, and the .aspx files (*and another file types like .ascx, .ashx, etc*) are considered even if it only has HTML inside,

> When the first request is made to an application, ASP.NET compiles
>   files in a specific order. The first items to be compiled are referred
>   to as the top-level items. After the first request, the top-level
>   items are recompiled only if a dependency changes.
>
> Top-level items include the App_GlobalResources folder, the
>   App_WebResources folder, profile properties, the App_Code folder, and
>   the Global.asax file. After the top-level items are compiled, ASP.NET
>   compiles additional items.
>
> These items include the App_LocalResources folder, individual ASP.NET
>   pages (.aspx files), ASP.NET user controls (.ascx files), ASP.NET HTTP
>   Handlers (.ashx files), and ASP.NET HTTP modules (.asmx files), as
>   well as themes, master pages, and other source files.

[From Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx#Anchor_2)

Answer (score 1):

Even when you upload an ASPX file that does have code content like `<script runat="server">` IIS will not recompile the site. Compilation will happen the first time someone hits that page.

But even if you do not have any server site code on the page, the C# or VB.Net compiler will fire up. It doesn't know that there is no code in there yet.

But as far as I know it will normally only compile the new page, not the whole site.